# Pytorch for Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: arm, pytorch, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

I have successfully cross compiled Pytorch 1.7 for Raspberry Pi3 B+ and the following wheel was generated as the result:

```
torch-1.7.0a0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl
```

However, when I try to install the wheel on the pi, I get this error:

```
ERROR: torch-1.7.0a0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

When I do lscpu, I see that the arm7l was correctly used as the target hw:

```
    Architecture:          armv7l
    Byte Order:            Little Endian
    CPU(s):                4
    On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
    Thread(s) per core:    1
    Core(s) per socket:    4
    Socket(s):             1
    Model:                 4
    Model name:            ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
    CPU max MHz:           1400.0000
    CPU min MHz:           600.0000
    BogoMIPS:              38.40
    Flags:                 half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32
```

And here is the output of pep425tags:

```
[('cp38', 'cp38', 'linux_armv7l'), ('cp38', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), 
('cp38', 'none', 'linux_armv7l'), ('cp37', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), 
('cp36', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), ('cp35', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), 
('cp34', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), ('cp33', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), 
('cp32', 'abi3', 'linux_armv7l'), ('py3', 'none', 'linux_armv7l'), 
('cp38', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ('py38', 'none', 
'any'), ('py3', 'none', 'any'), ('py37', 'none', 'any'), ('py36', 
'none', 'any'), ('py35', 'none', 'any'), ('py34', 'none', 'any'), 
('py33', 'none', 'any'), ('py32', 'none', 'any'), ('py31', 'none', 
'any'), ('py30', 'none', 'any')]
```

So I am wondering, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer, I had python 3.8 on my target hw (raspberry pi 3B+) and I used had python 3.7 on my build system. Downgrading python 3.8 to python 3.7 on target hw fixed the issue.